# Visual Studio 2017 - Go To Definition goes to .h file instead of .cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

When I right click and `"Go To Definition"` for the class I created in a separate `.cpp` file, it goes to the `.h` instead - identical behavior to `"Go To Declaration"`.

I thought the definition was the `.cpp` file, am I missing something?

I've tried deleting the `.vs` Intellisense folder for the project, cleaning and rebuilding the solution, doing `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`, updating Visual Studio, etc.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are confusing a class with a variable of that class. Your class is defined in the .h file.

Comment: Please refrain from posting images of your code, they are seldom helpful.

Comment: posting an image of the Visual Studio interface ;)

Comment: That makes sense, when I Go To Definition on the constructor, it goes to the .cpp file. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the *definition* of your class is there in your header (.h) file. It so happens that is also your class *declaration*. This is perfectly fine, and common practice.

You might also have declared your class, *or forward declared* your class like so:

```
class Burrito;
```

and later defined it in the way you have. You would probably see VS behave differently in this case by going to the declaration above, and the definition below. You would normally only do this if you needed to refer to it in the definition of another class.

Additionally, your class function members are also *declared* in your class definition, though they might be (and in your case are) *defined* elsewhere.